# How can I cache LINQ to SQL results safely?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, caching

I have an ASP.Net MVC web app that includes a set of Forums.  In order to maintain flexible security, I have chosen an access-control-list style of security.

However, this is getting to be a pretty heavy chunk of data to retrieve every time somebody views the forum index.

I am using the EnterpriseLibrary.Caching functionality to cache various non-LINQ items on the site. (The BBCode interpreter, the Skins, and etc.)

My question is this:

**What is the safest and most elegant way to cache a LINQ result?**

Essentially, I would like to keep a copy of the ACL for each forum in memory to prevent the database hit.  That way, for each person that hits the site, at most I would have to fetch group membership information.

All-in-all I'm really looking for a way to cache large abouts of LINQ data effectively, not just these specific rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've already got a caching system for general objects, all you should need is this:

```
var whatever = linkQuery.ToList();
```

Comment: Won't that prevent the garbage collector from calling the destructor of the DataContext?  I'm disposing of it properly, but I don't want it hanging around if I don't need to.

Comment: It shouldn't prevent garbage collection of the datacontext. The entity objects have no reference back to the DC. (The DC's change tracker may have a reference to the entity objects, but there's no reference back... ....so it shouldn't prevent a disposed dc from getting gc'd)